# oracle date time function error

Tags: oracle, datetime

I am working on following sql and keeping getting error on date part

Error i am getting is :- ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM  STGDBA.INTERACTIONS
  WHERE APP_ID='Home Depot'
  AND PEGA_ID ='0'
  AND TO_CHAR(to_date(END_TIME))BETWEEN TO_DATE('2012-AUG-01', 'YYYY-MON-DD')AND TO_DATE
('2012-AUG-31', 'YYYY-MON-DD')
```

This is how date is stored in database:- 2011-10-24 08:46:31.621

Comment: What is the data type of `end_time`?  Is it a `date`?  Or a `varchar2`?  Or something else?

Comment: it is VARCHAR2 (40 BYTE)

Comment: Why are you casting `END_TIME` back to a string if you're comparing it to 2 `Date` types?

Comment: What is the format of end_time?  'YYYY-MON-DD' also?  What happens if you specify that in the to_date for end_time?  Wait, why are you making it char?

Comment: this also gives me same error:-   SELECT to_date(END_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY')FROM STGDBA.INTERACTIONS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should never store date or timestamp data in a table using a `VARCHAR2` data type.  You should always use the proper data type (`date`, `timestamp`, `timestamp with time zone`, etc.).  Storing data in the wrong data type leads to performance problems (the optimizer's cardinality estimates are generally going to be much less accurate and indexing the column becomes much more problematic) as well as bugs that are difficult to find when some application inadvertently stores a string with the wrong format in your table causing various queries to start throwing errors or when subtle changes in execution plans cause errors to suddenly start (or stop) appearing.

Second, assuming every `end_time` string in every row in the table (whether or not the other two predicates are satisfied) is of the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FFF`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM  STGDBA.INTERACTIONS
  WHERE APP_ID='Home Depot'
  AND PEGA_ID ='0'
  AND to_date(substr(END_TIME,1,length(end_time)-4), 
              'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) BETWEEN TO_DATE('2012-AUG-01', 'YYYY-MON-DD')
                                            AND TO_DATE('2012-AUG-31', 'YYYY-MON-DD')
```

You always want to compare dates to dates and strings to strings so you don't want to wrap the left side of the expression with a `to_char`.  You always want to specify an explicit format mask when you call `to_date`, which is what I do here.  And a `date` does not have subsecond precision so you have to strip off the fractional seconds (this would not be an issue if you declared `end_time` to be a `timestamp(3)`).

Comment: Thank you that was really good explanation and it makes sense. Also i ran the qry above and it returns 0 recs. I tried the qry below 
select  to_date(substr(END_TIME,1,length(end_time)-4), 
              'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) 
   
  FROM  STGDBA.INTERACTIONS   and this returns in the format below 10/24/2011 8:46:31 AM, do i need to put time also along with my date ?

Comment: @user1683763 - The format of the string that gets displayed to you when you run that query is irrelevant.  It is based on either your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` or the configuration of whatever client tool you are using.  If the query does not return the data you expect, you'll need to show us the source data and tell us what output you expect.

Comment: Source data is like the data below:-                        END_DATE :- 2011-10-24 08:46:31.621

Comment: I tweaked teh qry lil bit and it worked thank you so much Justin.